# How to chain React Context dispatch? (Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What I want to do is sort of subscribe to a dispatch, then dispatch to another state. I've tried useEffect but it's giving me infinite loop and a few googling says to not update state on useEffect so now my code looks like this, but it's not working as intended.

```
const Chain = () => {
  const [fooState, fooDispatch] = fooOne() // useReducer
  const [barState, barDispatch] = barTwo() // useReducer

  const btnOnClick = () => {
    fooDispatch({ type: "UPDATE_FOO" })

    // Update barState base on the new value of foo, doesn't work. 
    // Foo is not yet updated.
    if (fooState.value == 'new value') {
      barDispatch({ type: "UPDATE_BAR" }) 
    }
    // fooState gets updated after this function block.
  }

  return <Button label="Button" onClick={btnOnClick} />
}

export default Chain
```

My useReducer code looks like this:
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

On line `if (fooState.value == 'new value') {`, React still haven't updated the value so I can't go inside the if block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use `useEffect` to keep the 2 reducer hooks in sync.

Hooks [can be optimized](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) to execute only when certain values change.
In your case, when `fooState.value` (or `fooState` if you don't want to be too strict).

Something like:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (fooState.value == 'new value') {
    barDispatch({ type: "UPDATE_BAR" }) 
  }
}, [fooState.value]);
```

should get you the behaviour you want - also remove `barDispatch` from `btnOnClick`

The executing order should be something like:

1. The user clicks the button and you call `fooDispatch`
2. The (foo)dispatch changes the `fooState` value which triggers a component re-render
3. Use `useEffect` to take action when `fooState` changed and calls the `barDispatch`

If `fooOne` and `barTwo` are frequently used together maybe you should combine them in a single reducer hook.

I don't know of any reason why you shouldn't set state (or other hooks) in `useEffect`. It is a bit tricky because you could get an infinite loop but there are cases where you need this.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Calls to `dispatch` are asynchronous, so you can not read the state until the next rerender.

Also you should dispatch an action that says what happened, not what you want to happen, if that makes sense. Your reducer should conceptually react to the user interaction or other event that has just taken place. This is why it is called React.

So what this means is the instead of dispatching `UPDATE_FOO`, you should dispatch `BTN_CLICKED` and then both the FOO and BAR reducers should listen for this action and decide if they need to update.

Comment: Looks like what I need. Do you have some example code with making a reducer listen to a dispatch?

Comment: Can you add you current reducer code to the question?